# How to get text from a div tag?

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to get text from div and put it in a text document using selenium c#. I cant seem to capture the text from div in variable

```
<div data-tid="messageContent" dir="auto"><div>new doc</div></div>
```

I tried these:

```
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']")).GetAttribute();
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']")).Text();
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']")).Text;
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Text` is a property, not method

```
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']/div")).Text;
```

`GetAttribute()` needs a parameter specifying the attribute to fetch

```
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']/div")).GetAttribute("textContent");
// or
var puttingDataInDoc = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@data-tid='messageContent']/div")).GetAttribute("innerHTML");
```

You should also target the child `<div>`, the text is there.

Comment: it did nothing, and the document stayed empty...the value in div in variable and cant be fixed in attribute like "textContent"

Comment: @Nina Try the `GetAttribute` methods.